# Android splash screen before white screen

Tags: android, html, css, splash-screen

my problem is In android mobiles when click on my application it is need to show the splash screen but in micromax a110 when I start the application an white screen is coming first then after only the splash screen is appearing. But For my application I need to display only splash screen not any white screen. The application is containing the html,css and javascript coding. SO please suggest any solution for this issue

Comment: I assume that is a performance issue in that device. Check whether do you have any code to display white screen?

Comment: check in any other device.

Comment: In other devices it is working fine but only this device has this prolbem.

Comment: No code to display white screen noundla

Answer (score 1):

```
  <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

**put this line in your style it prevents white screen from opening before splash**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have found that white screen is due to loading of DOM. In this case solution is to show a simple HTML page first which would say something like 'loading..' and then load your actual page with full of css and javascript.